# Generic typeahead field and initialiser

Tags: jquery, laravel, typeahead

How can I make a reusable typeahead.js field initialiser? I would like one single jQuery init function to set up all my typeahead fields. They will all get their data from remote, using a data-url attribute. For example my HTML might look something like this

```
<input type="text" id="filter_worker" 
   data-url="/search/autocomplete&searchfor=worker" 
   data-autocomplete="1" 
   placeholder="Staff Memeber" class="form-control" name="worker_id"
>
```

So all fields with data-autocomplete='1' would become typeahead fields. I'm using Laravel / Blade, if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on an older 0.9.3 version of typeahead, so none of the examples on the web were working for me.

jQuery

```
function setTypeaheadFields() {
    jQuery("[data-autocomplete='1']").each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var resultField = $(this).data('inputfield');
        var sourceUrl = $(input).data('url');
        var minLength = $(this).data('minLength') || 3;
        $(input).typeahead("destroy");
        $(input).typeahead({
            valueKey: 'text',
            name: 'text',
            minLength: minLength,
            remote: {
                url: sourceUrl + '/%QUERY',
                filter: function(parsedResponse) {
                    return parsedResponse;
                },
            template: [
                "<p class='label'><strong>{{text}}</strong></p>"
            ].join(''),
                engine: Hogan
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, datum) {
            $(resultField).val(datum.id); // If they select something, add the value to the hidden field
        }).on('typeahead:closed', function() {
            $(resultField).val(''); // If they just wrote their own answer in, clear the selection
        });
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="filter_worker" data-inputfield='#filter_worker_id' data-url="/search/autocomplete/getWorkerByName" data-autocomplete="1" placeholder="Staff Member" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="filter_worker_name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is relatively simple to do with jQuery. Just need to query for your target inputs, loop through them and initialize individually. Ex:

```
$('input[data-autocomplete=1]').each(function(){
  var $input = $(this),
      sourceUrl = $input.data('url');

  // Initialize
  $input.typehead({...})
});
```

Comment: I think it's more the // Initialize part I was getting confused by

Comment: Just need to follow the documentation and/or examples. Use the `sourceUrl` variable for the url. https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote

Comment: The project I'm on was using 0.9.3 of typeahead, which is why none of the examples were working for me